# "for x in" syntax with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, refactoring, nsarray

I've this kind of instruction:

```
[self someMethod:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
[self someMethod:CGPointMake(270, 50)];
[self someMethod:CGPointMake(50, 360)];
[self someMethod:CGPointMake(270, 360)];
...
```

I want to refactor code using NSArray like this:

```
NSArray items = [NSArray initWithObjects:
                  CGPointMake(50, 50),
                  CGPointMake(270, 50),
                  CGPointMake(50, 360),
                  CGPointMake(270, 360),
                  ...
                  nil];
```

I dont know right syntax, can someone help me? I'd tried with this, but XCode tells me "Selector element type CGPoint is not a valid object":

```
CGPoint point = [CGPoint alloc];

for (point in items) {
    [self someMethod:point];
}
```

Comment: `CGPoint` is a C struct, not an object.

Comment: @Simone - I edited your post for the spelling of syntax. I wasn't quite sure if you meant "for in" or foreign in your title, if you don't like my edit, roll it back or let me know.

Comment: If I am not wrong should not be `NSArray *items` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for-in` loops are an Objective-C concept for iterating over collection classes (that conform to NSEnumeration).  If you would like to iterate over C-structs (like CGPoints), use a standard for-loop with a C-array, or wrap the CGPoints in NSValues.

Here's what your refactoring would look like in modern Objective-C syntax:

```
NSArray *items = @[
                  [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)], //wrap the points in an
                  [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(270, 50)], //NSValue so they become
                  [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(50, 360)], //first class citizens
                  [NSValue valueWithPoint:CGPointMake(270, 360)],//(Y no boxing?*)
                 ]; //End of collection literal
for (NSValue *value in items) { //iterate through the NSValues with our points
    [self someMethod:[value pointValue]]; //'un-wrap' the points by calling -pointValue
}
```

<sub>*My personal struct boxing macro:</sub>

```
#define STRUCT_BOX(x) [NSValue valueWithBytes:&x objCType:@encode(typeof(x))];
```

Comment: Never knew about literal boxing for C structs...+1 for that

Comment: @John Boxing works for nearly everything... Oops, but points.  C-structs have to be wrapped explicitly. That sucks.

Comment: Boxing works only for NSNumber. None of the other NSValue types do it. The fact that you made this mistake simply shows that Apple should have done it!

Comment: @Anoop absolutely.  Great catch!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to resort to NSArray. As CodaFi says, "If you would like to iterate over C-structs (like CGPoints), use a standard for-loop with a C-array." Well then, why not do so?

```
static CGPoint items[] = {
    {50, 50},
    {270, 50},
    {50, 360},
    {270, 360},
};

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

This creates the array at compile-time, not run-time! Then iterate the array:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(items); ++i)
    [self someMethod:items[i]];
```

For another example involving an array of dictionaries, see [Objective-C Is Still C (Not Java!)](https://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-is-c/)